# BeautifulSoup doesn't parse XML loaded from local file

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

My `Python` script utilizing `BeautifulSoup` gets `None` when attempting to parse (find an element from) `XML` from a locally loaded file:

```
xmlData = None

with open('conf//test2.xml', 'r') as xmlFile:
    xmlData = xmlFile.read()

# this creates a soup object out of xmlData,
# which is properly loaded from file above
xmlSoup = BeautifulSoup(xmlData, "html.parser")

# this resolves to None
subElemX = xmlSoup.root.singleelement.find('subElementX', recursive=False)
```

The file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <singleElement>
        <subElementX>XYZ</subElementX>
    </singleElement>
    <repeatingElement id="1"/>
    <repeatingElement id="2"/>
</root>
```

I also have a REST GET service that returns the same XML but when I read that using [`requests.get`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), it is parsed fine:

```
resp = requests.get(serviceURL, headers=headers)

respXML = resp.content.decode("utf-8")

restSoup = BeautifulSoup(respXML, "html.parser")
```

Why does it work with the REST response and not with the data read out of a local file?

**UPDATE:** While I understand that python is case sensitive and single**e**lement !=single**E**lement, the case is disregarded when parsing the web service.

Comment: print `xmlData` and `respXML` and compare what you get.

Comment: `singleelement != singleElement`

Comment: funny, it works with the REST service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to make it work:

- change the features from `html.parser` to `xml` (you are parsing XML data, XML != HTML)
- change `singleelement` to `singleElement`

Changes applied (works for me):

```
xmlSoup = BeautifulSoup(xmlData, "xml")

subElemX = xmlSoup.root.singleElement.find('subElementX', recursive=False)
print(subElemX)  # prints <subElementX>XYZ</subElementX>
```

Comment: I got `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: @amphibient ah, yeah, you need `lxml` installed for this to work.

Comment: I tried `python -m pip install lxml` but got `ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640026/how-to-install-module-for-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, HTML is a case-insensitive language, so `html.parser` internally converts all tag names to lower case. Given that, the following line should work:

```
subElemX = xmlSoup.root.singleelement.find('subelementx', recursive=False)
```

But in general, you shouldn't parse XML documents with HTML parser. XML is quite strict about its syntax, and that's for a good reason.