# How to install module for BeautifulSoup XML parsing?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639421/1312080), I was told to not use `BeautifulSoup(xmlData, 'html.parser')` for `XML` parsing but to use `BeautifulSoup(xmlData, 'xml')`. That parser, however, does not come with `BeautifulSoup`.

As per one of the comments, I tried:

> python -m pip install lxml

But got:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command D:\SOFT\Python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\U
sers\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hl9fxzny\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__fi
le__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:
\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ivemv19a-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.4.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch
file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\
resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\reso
urces\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\reso
urces\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win
32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-
3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.
win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl ->
 build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win3
2-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\i
soschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "D:\SOFT\Python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\L
ocal\\Temp\\pip-build-hl9fxzny\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repl
ace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\pip-ivemv19a-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with err
or code 1 in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hl9fxzny\lxml\
```

I am using `Python 3.5.2` and would like **something that will work right out of `pip`**, meaning won't need to be compiled separately.

Comment: `lxml` can be compiled during instalation so it can need C/C++ source code or at least C?C++ header files `*.h` for `xslt` and `xml` libraries.

Comment: I need something more readily available...

Comment: see unofficial repo in answer below.

Comment: BTW: `lxml` uses `libxml.dll` and `libxstl.dll` so you have to install it first.

Comment: is there **any other** XML plugin for BeautifulSoup that works plug-n-play ?

Comment: you have in Python Standard Library `html.parser` so you don't have to install it.

Comment: BTW: there is Anaconda distribution which install Python from Python.org and many precompiled modules - for example `lxml`. It can be better solution for Windows users. [Anaconda Install](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and list of [installed packages](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs)

Comment: The answer I referenced explains why I shouldn't use that (but I am right now)

Comment: I would care for this answer - use `html.parser` and lower case names and it will work - if you need only read data from xml.

Comment: yes, I think that will be alright for my needs right now.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a compiler on Windows to install lxml through pip.

Some unofficial builds are available here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Find URL for the right wheel package then this should work:

```
pip install http://url_to_wheel
```

Comment: thanks but i was looking for something that works right out of `pip`

Comment: how do i point my pip to that repository ?  that could be a nice addition to the answer

Comment: Complicated on windows. You need to install Visual C++ express, and exactly the same version of VC++ that was used to compile Python. You also need to install libxml and libxslt sources. See instructions on lxml website... Lot of work.

Comment: @amphibient You download `.whl` file and use `pip install fullname.whl`

Comment: I get `lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: I just wonder what's so delicate about XML parsing to make this module so difficult to install

Comment: lxml calls the libxml and libxslt C libraries. first the libraries are not installed on Windows by default. Then the python lxml library needs to be compiled using the C libraries. On Linux the package manager and the general availability of gcc makes it not so painful, but to compile C on Windows in another story.