# How to replace/remove XML tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have XML in a local file that is a template for a final message that gets `POST`ed to a `REST` service. The script pre processes the template data before it gets posted.

So the template looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <singleElement>
        <subElementX>XYZ</subElementX>
    </singleElement>
    <repeatingElement id="11" name="Joe"/>
    <repeatingElement id="12" name="Mary"/>
</root>
```

The message XML should look the same except that the `repeatingElement` tags need to be replaced with something else (XML generated by the script based on the attributes in the existing tag).

Here is my script so far:

```
xmlData = None

with open('conf//test1.xml', 'r') as xmlFile:
    xmlData = xmlFile.read()

xmlSoup = BeautifulSoup(xmlData, 'html.parser')

repElemList = xmlSoup.find_all('repeatingelement')

for repElem in repElemList:
    print("Processing repElem...")
    repElemID = repElem.get('id')
    repElemName = repElem.get('name')

    # now I do something with repElemID and repElemName
    # and no longer need it. I would like to replace it with <somenewtag/>
    # and dump what is in the soup object back into a string.
    # is it possible with BeautifulSoup?
```

Can I replace the repeating elements with something else and then dump the soup object into a new string that I can post to my REST API?

**NOTE:**  I am using `html.parser` because I [can't get the xml parser to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640026/how-to-install-module-for-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing) but it works alright, understanding HTML is more permissive than XML parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) and [`.new_tag()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) methods:

```
for repElem in repElemList:
    print("Processing repElem...")
    repElemID = repElem.get('id')
    repElemName = repElem.get('name')

    repElem.replace_with(xmlSoup.new_tag("somenewtag"))
```

Then, you can dump the "soup" using `str(soup)` or `soup.prettify()`.

Comment: funny, i just came up with the same solution simultaneously

Comment: unfortunately, the only soup parser that works on my system (Win7) is `html.parser` (xml does not work as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640026/how-to-install-module-for-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing?noredirect=1#comment68512605_40640026) converts all tags to lower case and my REST API is case sensitive

Comment: soup.prettify add an xml tag